# Continuously check if button from usercontrol clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, events, user-controls, event-handling

I have a user control with the class name `PinPad`. It contains a `Button` which I handled its click event `btnGetAccess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` and a property for reading the `Password` entered in a `TextBox`.

I put an instance of `PinPad` control on my `Form1` and it's is supposed to open `Form2` when the button is clicked and the password is correct.

since I put it in constructor currently checking the password does nothing because it will only check the password when `Form1` loads and no password is entered yet.

So how can I make `Form1` continuously check the password after the button in user-control class was clicked?

Here is my current code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if (pinPad1.Password == "123456")
    {
        // open form2
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the whole if statement inside the button's click eventhandler?

Comment: Yes but i can't open and close a form from within the usercontrol. It has to be done in the form1 class.

Comment: Very unclear what you trying to achieve... If you need to run code all the time - use Timer (there are plenty of questions about that which you probably already read).

Comment: I just need to put the if statement somewhere other than the constructor so it will check the password more than once. Right now my code only checks password on form load but the password is empty (not entered yet)

Comment: You don't need to check a button click continuously. Events are created to subscribe them. Then they notify you when an event raised.

Comment: @RezaAghaei   If the button click event is in the user control class, how do I notify Form1 code that it is clicked?

Comment: You should create a new event in your user control and raise it for example when the button in your user control clicked. Then you can subscribe for that event in the form and run your logic there.

Comment: @RezaAghaei i thought about doing that.  What is the general syntax for checking if a event was raised in another class? (i.e. my user-control class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to check a button click continuously. Events are created to subscribe them. Then they notify you when an event raised.

You should create a new event in your user control and raise it for example when the button in your user control clicked. Then you can subscribe for that event in the form and run your logic there.

**Example:**

```
[System.ComponentModel.DefaultEvent("ButtonClicked")]
public partial class SampleControl: UserControl
{
    public SampleControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.Click += button1_Click;
    }

    public event EventHandler ButtonClicked;
    protected virtual void OnButtonClicked(EventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = ButtonClicked;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do Stuff then raise event
        OnButtonClicked(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

You can put the control on the form and handle its `ButtonClicked` event. Since we set `ButtonClicked` as default event of the control, when you double click on it in designer, it creates the event handler and subscribes for event:

```
private void sampleControl1_ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Button Clicked");
}
```

As a C# developer, you should learn about events as much as you know classes, methods, properties and etc. You can learn more about [Handling and Raising Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped a lot. I wasn't aware of DefaultEvent before.

Comment: You are my hero!

Answer (score -2):

Use [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7). There's a good example. Implement it, and don't forget to stop the timer after the password is correctly entered and checked.